# Swift - Find Specific Differences in Arrays of Structs

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, structure

If I have a structure, say:

```
struct Subject { 
 var subjectID: String?
 var name: String?
 var note: String?
}
```

And I have two arrays of this structure: Array1 and Array2.

For example:

```
Array1 = [(subjectID = "T", name = "H", note = "DF"), (subjectID = "F", name = "H", note = "SD")]
Array2 = [(subjectID = "T", name "G", note = "DF"), (subjectID = "R", name = "F", note = "SDF")]
```

I want to **return a new array**, which consists of a subset of elements from `Array2` that match the `subjectID` field of `Array1` but have different `name` and/or `note` elements.

In the example above, the **returned array** would be:

```
[(subjectID = "T", name "G", note = "DF")]
```

As it contains the same `subjectID` (in this case `T`) as in `Array1` but the `name` field is different. Note that the fields for this new returned array should be original values from `Array2` (ex: you don't need to correct them to match `Array1`)

Is there an easy way (ex: one-two lines of code) to do this without brute forcing it?

Thanks!

Comment: So, the output should be the matched `subjectID`, correct?

Comment: No, the output would be an `array` that contains only the elements of `Array2` that match the `subjectID` field of `Array1` but differ in any of the other structure vars

Comment: You want the new `Array` from second one, that's fix?

Comment: No, that's not fixed. Just the original elements from `Array2` that contain matching `subjectID's` from `Array1` but different fields otherwise.

Comment: What do you mean when you say without "brute-forcing" it? You could easily write a concise solution in one or two lines using `filter` and `find`, but the time complexity would be O(n*m) (n is length of array 1, m is length of array 2) so would technically be a "brute-force" solution. If you are after efficiency, you'll have to do some preprocessing and probably transform the first array into a set or hash of some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are good answers here, I prefer to keep the test simple.

First the setup

```
struct Subject {
    var subjectID: String?
    var name: String?
    var note: String?
}

let array1 = [Subject(subjectID: "T", name: "H", note: "DF"), Subject(subjectID: "F", name: "H", note: "SD")]
let array2 = [Subject(subjectID: "T", name: "G", note: "DF"), Subject(subjectID: "R", name: "F", note: "SDF")]
```

Now lets look at the actual algorithm. `array2.filter` returns an array of `Subject`s in the `array2` in which the block returns `true`. `array1.contains` returns `true` if any of the `Subject`s in `array1` returns `true`. The test itself is exactly what you described. Are the subject id equal and does either the name or the note differ.

```
let result = array2.filter { s2 in
    array1.contains { s1 in
        s1.subjectID == s2.subjectID && (s1.name != s2.name || s1.note != s2.note)
    }
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion. However, I think that all of the answers will take O(n²).

Comment: @AhmadF Unless there are performance issues, I would avoid a more complex solution. I've found that optimizing for maintainability is better when performance is not an issue.

Comment: This is the most concise and clean answer. Thank you so much for the input and time!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
let subjectsByID = Dictionary(grouping: array1, by: { $0.subjectID })

let diff = array2.filter { subject in
    if let other = subjectsByID[subject.subjectID]?.first {
        return subject.name != other.name || subject.note != other.note
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
```

It groups the subjects in the first array by ID and then filters the second array based on whether or not there is an entry for that ID with a different name or note.  You didn't specify what to do if there are multiple entries in the first array with the same ID so it just looks at the first one.

Comment: You need to loop through the results of `subjectsByID[subject.subjectID]`, not just take the first one.

Comment: @JefferyThomas I mentioned in my answer that I picked the first one because he didn't specify what do if there were multiple entries with the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

You could *filter* the second array elements based on the first array elements, as:

```
let Array1 = [Subject(subjectID: "T", name: "H", note: "DF"), Subject(subjectID: "F", name: "H", note: "SD")]
let Array2 = [Subject(subjectID: "T", name: "G", note: "DF"), Subject(subjectID: "R", name: "F", note: "SDF")]

let result = Array2.filter { subject -> Bool in
    for s in Array1 {
        if subject.subjectID == s.subjectID && subject.name != s.name && subject.note != s.subjectID { return true }
    }

    return false
}
```

`result` should contains what are you asking for. Keep in mind that it has the complexity of nested iteration (`O(n²)`).

Answer (score 0):

I used a forEach and filter in combination to find the requested elements

```
var result = [Subject]()
arr1.forEach( { subject in
    result.append(contentsOf: arr2.filter( { $0.subjectID == subject.subjectID && 
                                            ($0.name != subject.name || 
                                             $0.note != subject.note) }))
})
```

To get a little cleaner code the check could be made into a function in the struct

```
struct Subject {
   ...

    func isModifiedComparedTo(_ subject: Subject) -> Bool {
        return self.subjectID == subject.subjectID && (self.name != subject.name || self.note != subject.note)
    }
}

var result = [Subject]()
arr1.forEach( { subject in
    result.append(contentsOf: arr2.filter({$0.isModifiedComparedTo(subject)}))
})
```